# Changing the primary DNS server address for all domains administered by my OVH account

Tags: dns-servers

Is there any way to change the primary DNS server address for all the domains administered by my [OVH](https://www.ovh.com/) account at once?

Changing the primary DNS server address one domain at a time is tedious:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea, but I can empathize. GoDaddy only recently added a bulk change option. I had to go down about 30 domains and change them one at a time. I have fewer now, but I still would prefer a bulk update.

Comment: Writing an iMacros script is always an option.